# Substituting the CD4006 with a CD4021

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

During a YouTube session, I stumbled upon an interesting circuit.  I just had to digitize it and archive it.

Since the CD4006 is pretty hard to obtain for several years now, like Mouser doesn't offer them although Texas instruments indicates it as active, I thought the [CD4021](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4021b-q1.pdf) might be a close substitute.

[image]

[image]

Although it is not the same, would it do the job? Albeit using 6 and 7 stages instead of 4 and 5 as in the CD4006.

Did I terminate the unused pins correctly, since the datasheet show them as inverters?
as the parallel to serial pin being tied to low.

Comment: What is the purpose of that circuit ? Every reader could spend time to carefully look at the schematics and find out what its supposed behavior is. But it would be much more efficient to provide all the contextual information, behavior, expected performances, etc, into the question body. You would get more answers by doing so.

Comment: Seems to be a random generator ?

Comment: @Blup1980, ah, forgot about that, it's a pseudo random generator, just wanted to know if the Cd4021 is terminated  properly.

Comment: Seems ok, with the unusual use of an inverter and "quick" feedback from the first shifts ... (not the "longest" PRBS ?).
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Comment: @Antonio51, that's looks very interesting, thanks, the "Fibonacci LFSR", but i got 12V, so i have to stick the the CD4021.

Comment: @Antonio51, you need to inverter to get it going.

Comment: Ok. I did not know if the start phase was necessary. Generally, I think, by shifting a logic 1 as first bit. Some LFSR don't need it if polynomial well chosen.

Comment: @Antonio51, i tried the one from the article you gave me and it didn't start until i put the transitor in it. i have chosen for a 30 bit setup, 2 x 8 and 2 x 7, alternating, 3 XOR gates like the article, not sure if it takes months or years to repeat at approx 30kHz. don't know the math for that. hopefully i terminated the Cd4021 properly, normally the datasheet say by terminating unused pins tie them low. amazing circuit. the CD4006 was a chip that toke me like years to figure out.

Comment: @NaturalDemon  Ok for the starting with the inverter, will try it with only 8 bits. The length of the sequence is 2^30 bits / 30kHz, so it will repeat every ... ~ 35792 seconds, unless I made an error.

Comment: @Antonio51, thank you again, would you be so kind to explain the formula. 2 to the power of 30? where did you derive the 2 from? 35792 seconds to repeat is still impressive, that's still almost half a day.

Comment: @Antonio51 because a bit is to the power of 2?

Comment: Yes ... but length could be shorter ... if feedback is not "good" chosen. For measuring the length, do a "compare" with a known state ... that wait the next exact "compare" ... or measure the time between "pulse" compare.

Comment: @Antonio51, like i said, it's pretty much the same as the wiki article, but i placed the taps on bit 8, bit 15, 23 and 30. so i have a tap of each of the 4021's