# CD4040 clock input

Tags: clock, cmos

Would you place a Cd40106 inverter before the clock input of a CD4040 or would you be half a cycle to late compared to the rest? ... while clocking a shift register.

since the CD4040 is negative edged.
Or does that mean if the clock pulse goes down to shift the next data, the counter advances and no inverter needed.

I wanna count how many bits are clocked in the shift register.

I have 2 variants

From the first I'm pretty sure, it does what i want (accept for the Cd40106). i clock in 16 bits and cut off the clock. after a gate hat outputted   the data, new should be clock in.

[image]

to avoid the negative edge thingy, i made a second possible "solution".
[image]

Comment: What edge does your shift register clock on? You have 50:50 chance of making the right choice!

Comment: @Kartman I have updated the question with images what i wanna do.

Comment: maybe i am misunderstanding what you are saying, but I do not see a clear description of what you are trying to do ... I also do not see a description of a problem

Comment: @jsotola, i wanna clock in 16 bit of data and have the Cd4040 on the correct edge.
the first image is what i think the best solution. after a manual gate has been applied, new data is shuffled in and waiting for the next gate.

Comment: At a glance the logic looks ok. Not sure what the 4040 does when the reset is active and clock low. There’s no filtering on the input. RF etc might spoil your day.

Comment: @Kartman, Thank's for you reply, what for filter would you recommend. low pass, 100pf / 100R in of the Cd4040 or? the CD4040 counts up to 16, resets if self and the CD4013 and go in waiting state ( for the first image) the CD4013 gets activated after receiving a Gate signal.

Comment: @Kartman the circuit that comes in front of this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590709/substituting-the-cd4006-with-a-cd4021?noredirect=1#comment1549243_590709  and that's where the clock is coming from, any advice is gratefully  appreciated.

Comment: Advice? Use a microcontroller! The 70’s wants its 4000  series cmos back!

Comment: @Kartman, haha, that's the idea, old skool. i uploaded a new images, removed the CD40106 inverter from the clock input on the Cd4040 and used a CD4066 switch to tie the Clock pin to GND when the Clock signal is removed, so it aint floating.

besides, you have the problem of 5 Volt ( old mcu's ) and 3.333 Volt in a bipolar 12 Volt system. it's a for an analog synthesizer.

Comment: Wasn’t a problem back in the 70’s. I work on a few late 70’s/80’s synths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130607/discussion-between-naturaldemon-and-kartman).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a much stronger look and define *exactly* what you are trying to do.  You have more fundamental issues than just which edge is triggering your counter.

1. You are using an analog switch to control your clock.  Analog switches weren't really meant for this and do weird things in the transition times.
2. The logic you have put together is "If Q, then clock.  If not Q, then ground".  That is exactly the same logic as a 2-input AND gate which will be *FAR* more reliable.
3. You are doing something called "clock gating".  Clock gating is not a simple thing and you can wind up with lots of weird glitches if you don't do it right.  See: https://anysilicon.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-clock-gating/
4. You are using a D-Flip Flop as an R-S Latch.  This ... works.  But a CD4043 or CD4044 lets you choose whether S takes priority or R takes priority.
5. It looks like you are trying to detect an edge with that R-C pair.  That's not going to work very reliably--especially if the frequency changes.  You really want to detect that edge with digital logic.  Put a flop in the path clocked by CLOCK and then use an AND gate again.  See: https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-positive-edge-detector

Finally, at the end of everything, you *might* actually want the RESET signal coming from the CD4040 to be on the negative edge if your clock gating circuitry is operating on the rising edge.

Of course, this all assumes that you need this to be relatively clean and reliable.  The combination of plug jack and CD4000 series CMOS suggests that you might be creating a guitar pedal.  At which point, "correct" doesn't matter so much as "does something that sounds cool".

Good luck.

Comment: Indeed a AND gate is better than the CD4066 for this, Thank you. the the logic table CD4043 seams what I'm looking for, it is dip16 vs dip14 for the CD4013, but also like 50% cheaper. i have used the "R-C pair" before, 1nF with 22K, while other use 10K, calculation shows 1ms @ 12 volt, but i didn't work on my synth, so i used 22k and it worked fine, might have a try with 15K.

Comment: i have taken your advice on the negative edge thing, replaced it with a Cd4017 and used the second flip flip from the CD4013 in combination with a AND gate to count and have the CD4017 run twice to count 16, better so? added a new image.

Comment: Okay, it *looks* like you want "On rising edge of gate, clock in 8 bits from data".  If that is the case, why are you tying GATE to both the STR(STROBE) and OE(OUTPUT ENABLE) on the 4094?

Comment: well, the "strobe" advances the data to the latch and output it directly, but i could tie OE permanently high and call it a day.

Comment: STR(STROBE) is there to allow you to do things like "Wait for all 8 bits to get clocked in and then put them all on the bus at the same time."  Since you're presenting every bit, there is no reason not to tie STR to Vdd.  Also, with 4000-series CMOS, prefer lower numbers (with some exceptions) and inverting gates.  Don't use AND/OR gates, use NAND/NOR gates.  Also, a 2 input NAND or NOR can be configured as an inverter (tie both inputs together).  That way you don't have to use an extra chip (a 4093 is also schmitt trigger like the 40106 if you genuinely need it).

Comment: I really recommend you find a copy of Don Lancaster's "CMOS Cookbook" somewhere.  It's really good for the kind of thing your trying to do.